# How can I use laravel partial view by angular js in templateURL

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I want to show a laravel blade view file in angular JS directive by

```
var commentsApp = angular.module('CommentApp',[]);

commentsApp.directive('commentForm',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: 'true'
        templateURL: 'views/comments/comment-form.blade.php'
    }
});
```

I want to use it by angular directive instead of 
`@include('comments.comment-form')`
Where is my problem? How to solve this. 
Thank you.

Comment: give the laravel route thats all :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you must define a route in laravel

```
Route::get('comment-form', function() {
    return view('comments.comment-form');
});
```

Then you can use it in AngularJS

```
var commentsApp = angular.module('CommentApp', []);

commentsApp.directive('commentForm', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: 'true',
        templateURL: 'comment-form'
    }
});
```

Comment: You could use wildcard for route to dynamically get views and end up with only one route for getting views.

Comment: How can you do that please?

Answer (score 0):

Answer above is a good idea, however i dont like the idea of asking for a template by routing, We would create a route for each component :c . I leave my solution here:

1. In gulpfile.js inside elixir function add this line:

```
 


     var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
        elixir(function(mix) {
            mix.copy('resources/assets/js/angular/components/**/*.template.html', public/angular-templates'); 
//Find all files with suffix .template.html
    });
```

As you notice it, i created a folder called 'angular' and then another one called 'components', there we will have our components

```
    Angular----------------------------- 
    --Components------------------------ 
    ----my-component.directive.js------- 
    ----my-component.template.html------
```

2. We have to create a global angular variable taking our browser window origin (www.myapp.com, localhost:8000, etc) by doing:

```
    angular.module('myModule',[])
    .value('pathAssets', location.origin + '/angular-templates/')
```

3. In our templateUrl we will call the template by writting:

```
    templateUrl: pathAssets + '../angular-templates/my-template.html',
```

I have to say we have to concat our angular files in a file, otherwise it won't work D: if you don't know how to do it, add these lines in your gulpfile.js

```
    mix.scripts([
        '../../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
        'angular/app.js',
        'angular/controllers/**/*.controller.js',
        'angular/components/**/*.directive.js',
        'angular/bootstrap.js',
], 'public/js/app.js'); //We concatenate angular files saving them in app.js
```

4. Finally execute the command 'gulp' in terminal(In our project), it should generate a new folder in public called angular-templates.

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('app').component('bringTeamToEvent', {
  templateUrl: '/assets/ng/app/team/bringTeamToEvent.html',
  bindings: {
    hero: '='
  }
});
})(window.angular);
```

Just work from the public directory, no need to compile assets and move if you dont need to.

Then add the @ symbol to tell blade to ignore and let angular do its work within the template

`<span>Name: @{{ $ctrl.hero.name}}</span>`